# Build an executable jar with external dependancies from intelij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, executable-jar

I have a java console app with 5 classes and has one dependancy, gradle, com.google.code.gson.
I do build an executable jar successfully, however I get the following error when I execute the jar using the command `java -jar <jarName>.jar`

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)

**Creating the artifact:**

1. File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> "Click on Plus button" -> JAR -> From module with dependancies

I expected the jar file to run

Comment: Can you open the jar file in the ZIP editor of your choice and check if the com/google subtree is in there? According to your description IDEA should have put the necessary libraries in your Jar (building a UberJar or FatJar), but that seems to have failed. Generally speaking if you already use Gradle I wouldn't use the IDEA-way of generating that, but change your gradle script to build a fat jar instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "org.example.Main"
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

IDEA Gui Right Side :  Gralde Tab , YourProject -> `Tasks` -> `jar`

Find output jar file : YourProject -> build/libs : yourApp.jar

```
java -jar yourApp.jar
```

This method is create a fat jar, include dependencies class, only one jar.

No need other external jar files.